# How do I configure a network interface that has a predictable network interface name?

Tags: networking, ethernet

Due to predictable network interface names, what I believe to be my ethernet interface is named enp8s0. When I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure the interface to have a static IP, `ifconfig` showed that the IP I had given it was assigned. However, I was unable to actually connect to the internet.
Here is my configuration:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.252
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

I tried changing eth0 to enp8s0 and adding it to the `auto` line, but nothing seems to work. I'm either able to have an IP of `10.0.0.252` or I can connect to the internet. I can't seem to have both. What am I doing wrong? This setup worked perfectly fine on my RaspberryPi, which is doesn't have predictable network interface names.

Comment: Why did you use "iface eth0", if the interface name is enp8s0? Also, there aren't any DNS servers, is it intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What *IS* the name of the ethernet interface? In later Ubuntu versions, it is probably not `eth0`. Find out with:

```
ifconfig
```

Guessing that it may be `enp8s0`, I suggest that you amend your file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet static
address 10.0.0.252
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Reboot and check:

```
ifconfig
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. I could have sworn I already tried that. I guess I must have done the `auto` thing wrong. Thanks a bunch.